# Finding line breaks in a selection with Javascript?

Tags: javascript, html

Please excuse the amateurish of the below, it's coming from a designer attempting to code :D

What I'm trying to achieve here is to return the amount of lines selected/highlighted with the cursor. By "lines" I refer to what is visible to the user, not a line of HTML code (which it is doing at the moment). Also by "line break", I'm not referring to the HTML tag, but a typographic break, or "soft return".

So I'm currently stuck on `selection.split("\n")`, which splits only at "new lines" of course. Is there a way of splitting the selected string by line breaks instead?

Hopefully this all makes sense!

```js
function measure() {
  var str = window.getSelection();
  var selection = str.toString();
  var arr = selection.split("\n");
  if (arr != ""){
    document.getElementById('length').innerHTML = arr.length;
  }
  else {
    document.getElementById('length').innerHTML = "0";
  }
};

document.addEventListener('mouseup', measure, false);
```

```css
body {
  width: 80%;
}
```

```html
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur.</p>
<p>Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum. Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudantium, totam rem aperiam, eaque ipsa quae ab illo inventore veritatis et quasi architecto beatae vitae dicta sunt explicabo.</p>
<p><em>Selected lines:</em> <span id="length">0</span></p>
```

Comment: You can take a look at: https://github.com/xdamman/js-line-wrap-detector which is a JS Library that allows you to detect line-wraps in an html-element

Answer (score 0):

You could try to find out how many rectangles make up the selection. If you check where they start, you should be able to figure out how many lines are selected. The code goes something like this:

```
function measure() {
  var str = window.getSelection();

  var range = str.getRangeAt(0);
  var rects = range.getClientRects();
  document.getElementById('length').innerHTML = rects.length;
};

document.addEventListener('mouseup', measure, false);
```

Of source a selection can consist of more than one range and the rectangles can be on the same line, so you would need to add some more code to check for that.

Hope this helps!